# Conditionally prevent an object from being serialized to XML at runtime

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

How could logic be implemented to conditionally prevent an object from being serialized?  For example, if the list below is serialized to XML, only 500 of the `MyType` instances should show up in the result.  Whether or not an instance of `MyType` should be serialized is only known at runtime.

```
List<MyType> custom_types = new List<MyType>( 1000 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filter the list using linq prior to serialization;

serialize(custom_types.where(t = > t.Prop = value).ToList());

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  I was hoping there was a way to do this in the IXMLSerializable.WriteXml() method, but it writes the outer element for you.  This method is slightly less convenient, but gets the job done.  Thanks.

Comment: Actually, that is a good point.  You could Inherit the XML Serializer class and filter it in there, if you wanted to make it modular.